# Basic chat application with socket/node/express - Nothing gets printed out

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am just trying to do a very basic chat application with socket.io and node. I am unable to see anything get printed out to my screen, and cannot find any errors. Appreciate the help!

Thanks.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running...');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send-message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<title>Chat Test</title>

<style> #chat{
height: 500px;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>

<div id = "chat"></div>

<form id = "send-message">
    <input size = "35" id = "message"></input>
    <input type = "submit"></input>
    </form>

    <script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>

    JQuery(function($){

        var socket = io.connect();

        var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
        var $messageBox = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');

        $messageForm.submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('send-message', $messageBox.val());
        $messageBox.val('');

        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data){
        $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using jQuery, you must spell it `jQuery`, not `JQuery` or you could just use the built-in alias `$`.

This should have shown an error in the debug console of the browser which is something you should learn to look for to see your own errors.

```
jQuery(function($){

    var socket = io.connect();

    var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
    var $messageBox = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');

    $messageForm.submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('send-message', $messageBox.val());
        $messageBox.val('');

    });

    socket.on('new message', function(data){
        $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

After fixing this and then running your code and accessing `http://localhost:3000`, your app works just fine for me.  Anything submitted in the form is broadcast to all connected clients.

Comment: Thank you, I should have known about using developer tools. I'm just so used to compiled languages that show you the error right away. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2411290 - Javascript is different than compiled languages so you do have to change your habits.  While developing/testing, I always look in the debug console (on both client and server), even when things seem to be generally working because that's one place where you may see something is not as it should be and need to go investigate.  And, of course, anytime something isn't working properly, that's the first place to look for a clue.